# Can I design angular moving menu for android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I design angular moving menu for android?

[image]This image is for reference. The Buttons should scroll on the angular path and the centered button should be focused always.

Comment: Look at this github android project . https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure you can do it. The xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Next" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can we scroll the buttons if i add more buttons to this layout?

Comment: then you have to place different scrollviews inside the relative layout